# ORDER BY With possible missing column

Tags: sql

I have this DB with 2 fields, updateDate, and createDate, pretty self explanatory.

Now, my issue is that updateDate might not exist at times, and just a createDate.
I want to order by newest date, but I can't seem to find a way to order correctly, my first approach was to do the following:

```
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN "updateDate" = '' THEN "createDate"
ELSE "updateDate"
END
DESC
```

And this partially works, it gives priority to updateDate, and then sorts by createDate.
However, the issue occurs that it gives priority to sorting by updateDate, and then by createDate (Not entirely wrong, updateDate should have priority over createDate on the same date), so if there was a createDate with no updateDate newer than the updateDates, it will be placed at the bottom anyway like this:

```
Item | updateDate | createDate
1       24/1/2019     1/1/2005
2       23/1/2019     1/1/2005
3       22/1/2019     1/1/2005
4                    23/1/2019
5                    22/1/2019
```

How should I do this so it sorts like this?

```
Item | updateDate | createDate
1       24/1/2019     1/1/2005
2       23/1/2019     1/1/2005
4                    23/1/2019
3       22/1/2019     1/1/2005
5                    22/1/2019
```

Thanks

EDIT: The SQL engine is SAP HANA, which is kind of undocumented, but from my testing, regular SQL like MySQL should work.

Comment: What SQL technology you using?

Comment: SAP HANA, Standard SQL should work

Comment: Why you compare a datetime with an empty string? You really store strings in a date column?

Comment: No, they're date objects, but i didnt know how to compare to a "null", but seems like the engine understood what i wanted

Comment: `order by coalesce(updateDate, createDate) desc`

Comment: Null values are "compared using `IS [NOT] NULL`. E.g. `WHERE "updateDate" IS NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fall back to `createDate` when `updateDate` is missing, `coalesce()` might work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY coalesce("updateDate", "createDate");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! waiting for the timer to select as answer.
I had to modify it to `coalesce("updateDate","createDate")` due to the engine not recognizing those as columns otherwise, but it worked.

Comment: Great, I corrected that in the answer so if someone runs into it, it would work right away.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IFNULL  for order by

```
select * 
from my_table  
order by  ifnull(updateDate, createDate) DESC
```

http://sap.optimieren.de/hana/hana/html/sql_function_ifnull.html

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(updateDate) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY updateDate DESC) as [last_update]
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY nvl(updateDate, createDate);

You can use this as well